# Vue toggle through multiple button states

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I can't seem to find a solution for toggling through 4 states of button classes.   I'm trying to modify the "isFollowing"  kind of code but am dead ending.   I'm just trying to toggle through an off state and 3 colors.

```
<button v-on:click="market(p)"
                  v-bind:class="p.isFollowing ? following : not-following"></button>


methods: {
  market: async function (symbol) {
      if (symbol.isFollowing){
        
      } else {
        //send post
      }
      this.symbol.forEach(u => {
        if (u.symbol == symbol.symbol) {
          const id = symbol.symbol
          u.symbol = "TEMP"
          u.isFollowing = !u.isFollowing
          u.symbol = id
        }
      })
  }
}


//cant get this to work:

<button v-on:click="market(p)"
                  v-bind:class="['marketButton', { 'marketButtonOff': p.marketOff, 'marketButtonGreen': p.marketGreen, 'marketButtonYellow': p.marketYellow, 'marketButtonRed': p.marketRed }]
                  "></button>
```

Comment: How does the variable `p` looks like? Are the 4 states mutually exclusive?

Comment: How does your `symbol` data set look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a test component that uses a button click handler to change a data value.  This change in data value triggers an update of a computed property that returns the button class.

```
<template>
  <div class="multiple-button-states">
    <button type="button" :class="buttonClass" @click="changeButtonState">Trigger color change</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        buttonState: 1
      }
    },
    computed: {
      buttonClass() {
        let returnClass = ''
        switch(this.buttonState) {
          case 2:
            returnClass = 'green';
            break;
          case 3:
            returnClass = 'blue';
            break;
          case 4:
            returnClass = 'yellow';
            break;
          default:  // 1
            returnClass = 'red';
        }

        return returnClass;
      }
    },
    methods: {
      changeButtonState() {
        if (this.buttonState === 4) {
          this.buttonState = 1;
        }
        else {
          this.buttonState++;
        }
      }
    }

  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  .red {
    background-color: red;
  }

  .green {
    background-color: green;
  }

  .blue {
    background-color: blue;
  }

  .yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!  Does this sit well with Vue syntax?   I'll probalby have a few questions, but thanks for this great start!

Comment: This seems to be pure javascript,  are you familiar with Vue syntax?

Comment: I'm experienced with Vue.  My example is a Single File Component in my Vue CLI sandbox app containing Vue directives such as v-bind (:class) and v-on(@click), methods, computed, etc.  Not uncommon to have vanilla JS in a vue component.  Vue written in JS after all.

Comment: Any idea how to run this over looped objects?  The error i'm currently getting is: Property or method "buttonClass" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  If you create a CodeSandbox for you project (or a simplified project that focuses on the problem) it would help to analyze.